# "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages" when trying to install a package. Nothing has worked from other threads

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation

**The Problem**

I am trying to install Dolphin Emulator but every time I try it gives me an error. Anything I try doesn't work including many other thread's solutions.

```
sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
dolphin-emu : Depends : libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**What I Have Tried**

I have tried many other thread's solutions to fix the problem. I have tried

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo aptitude install dolphin-emu

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get distro-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu

sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Also, I have no packages that have do with Dolphin Emulator. I have gone into Synaptic and when I went into Synaptic->Custom Filters->Broken nothing shows up. Also in Edit->Fix Broken Packages nothing happens. In `software-properties-gtk,` all my repositories are enabled.

Can someone please help me? I have been searching all over the web and I still haven't found anything. I would appreciate it so much. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple. There isn't the right `libstdc++6` in the Ubuntu repositories for Trusty. You need an additional [PPA](http://ppa:dolphin-emu/ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/gcc-for-dolphin
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. This solved the problem completely

Comment: @A.B.

im still getting the error despite trying the above solution. Ideas?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid No. Ask a new question :)